# Grunt task with multiple options

Tags: gruntjs

What is the expected format for passing multiple options (with no value) to a grunt task?

For example, I have a task called 'migrate' that can be run in verbose mode, or dryrun mode. I would expect to run it with both options like:

```
$grunt migrate --dryrun --rollback
```

Unfortunately grunt seems to parse the options like:

```
{dryrun: '--rollback'}
```

instead of:

```
{dryrun: true, rollback: true}
```

Is there a problem parsing multiple parameters when one option follows another with no value? I can successfully run the task like:

```
$grunt migrate --dryrun=1 --rollback=1
```

Comment: You could use the target syntax, but that wouldn't really be very standard: `grunt migrate:dryrun:rollback`. Then in your handler function you can access those targets with `this.args`.

Comment: Just stumbled across this. I expect it to be a bug. I couldn't find an issue for it on github so I created one. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1173

Comment: Turns out there were many! Should've searched better haha it's late where I'm at. Here it is. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/908

Answer (score -4):

Use the default options, and it works:

```
grunt copy --verbose --help
grunt copy --help --verbose
```

Use two grunt statements with a semicolon between each statement to run a specific task with different options sequentially:

```
grunt jshint --debug; grunt jshint --verbose
```

Use two grunt statements with a semicolon between them to run the default task with different options sequentially:

```
grunt --version; grunt --help
```